# URL-Format with question mark

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, url

I have this update method in controller, and this url works:
http://localhost:5000/Ad/update/id/1/isActive/false

Is there a way I can make the url include question mark and parameters so that it'll be on this form:

http://localhost:5000/Ad/update?id=2&newStatus=false

```
[HttpPut("update/id/{id:int}/isActive/{newStatus:bool}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Update(int id, bool newStatus)
        {
            some code.....
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters that come after the `?` are the same ones you pass as a part of the URL. Meaning if you say `{id:int}`, I can type the same thing as `?id=123` as a part of the URL. It's just a way to format the URL to an SEO and human-friendly format. So no, there's no way you could be able to control what is passed to you. You can, however, validate the inputs that are passed to your action.

Comment: I'm not really trying to control what is passed. The url above was just an example of the format I want it on, so instead of using many "/" I want to use question mark and parameters

Comment: @sheima That's what I'm saying. So the client can either type something like `blog/post/123` or `blog/post?id=123` on their browser and both of these will work. But if you set things up correctly, the links that you generate on your website will have an SEO-friendly format. Also, I'd recommend to remove the `/id` part from the URL and have something more meaningful (like my example on the blog post)